# Laravel 5.2 How to lazy load a relationship onto a many-to-many relationships results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to extend a many-to-many relationship between in this case Events and Users with a pivot table of event_user:

```
// EVENT MODEL

public function invites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'event_user')
                ->withPivot('attendance');
}

// USER MODEL

public function invites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'event_user')
                ->withPivot('attendance');
}
```

That the user results contain their profile as well? So for example using:

```
// USER MODEL

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
}
```

And something like:

```
$event->invites()->with('profile')->get();
```

Currently right now `$event->invites;` provides a list of all the users, but without their associated profiles.  So the only way I can see to do this is to re-query the users based on a list of IDs I'd extract from the result collection, seems like it could be easier, but using lazy loading of either `user.profile` or `profile` says the method or value is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do nested eager loading refer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$event->with('invites.profile')->get();
```